# Facebook assertion crashes in iOS 3.1 sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

Facebook new sdk crashes

Assertion failure in -[FBSession urlSchemeSuffix], /Users/clang/tmp/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:508
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBSession: should only be used from a single thread'

Can any one know why this crashes...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're accessing your `FBSession` instance from more than one thread. Check that you're not calling `[FBSession activeSession]` or anything similar from a background thread (or that you're always calling it from the same background thread).

Comment: Assertion failure in -[FBSession close], /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:  I am getting this error for iOS 6.0